# How to use underscore.js sortBy

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm trying to rearrange a multidimensional array from a json file in my underscore template so that I can print out the disease from highest # of cases to lowest # of cases

The problem comes from the sortBy function not actually sorting the arrays.

here is an example Array that I'm working with

The totalCases array looks like:
    [163, 134, 98, 118, 2, 167, 152, 102, 49, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1265]

And the sortBy function is:

```
 <% _.sortBy(totalCases , function (num) { %>
    <%= num %>
 <% }); %>
```

it returns 
    163, 134, 98, 118, 2, 167, 152, 102, 49, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1265

I don't know what is going wrong with how I'm using the sortBy

Comment: WTH are you mixing `sortBy` (for sorting and returning an array) with templates (for outputting)???

Comment: `sortBy` takes a property to sort on!

Comment: added a property to return, but still not sorting 

`code` totalCases = {1 : {"CD":163}, 2 :{"CD":98}, 3 : {"CD":118}};
        _.sortBy(totalCases, function(num){
          return num.CD;
         });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing view with controller somehow. You don't want to rearrange the array *in the* underscore template, but before presenting it. Reread the [docs for `sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy), it takes a callback for the sort criteria or a property name or so, you don't want to output anything in there.

```
<%  var sortedCases = _.sortBy(totalCases, function(case) {
        return // your sort criteria here, e.g. `case.occurences`
    });
%><ol><%
    _.each(sortedCases, function(case) { %>
        <li><%= case /* … */ %></li>
<%  } %></ol>
```

Comment: That works except for it is sorting it from lowest to highest.  So I added .reverse() to the sortedCasses variable.

Comment: Or you inverse the sort criteria, for numbers you can easily do that by negating them.